# ACE editor: how to move changed data to $_POST or $_GET

Tags: javascript, html, ace-editor

I just discovered the ACE editor today and I have been playing with it and it is pretty slick. Although I'm not an expert in JavaScript most of the functionality is rather intuitive. The only issue I am having is how to move the changes to $_POST, $_GET or $_SESSION when I am done editing the file? You will see I am then executing a PHP file to save the changes to a MySQL table.

Here is my Html/JavaScript code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>ACE in Action</title>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    body {
      background-color: #ffff;
      color: #333;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .editor_container {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .editor_container form {
      margin: 45px;
      width: 90%;
      border: thin #333;
      border-radius: 8px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    .ace_gutter-cell {
      color: white;
      !important
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="editor_container">
    <h1>Ace Editor</h1>
    <form action="update.php" method="post">
      <h2>Edit the CSS file</h2>
      <div id="editor" title="css edit:" style="height: 500px; width: 80%; float: right;">
        .wrdAdmin { border-radius: 8px; border: solid thin #333; margin: auto; padding: 40px; position: relative; /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ffffff+0,ededed+100 */ background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers
        */ background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #ededed 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */ background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#ededed 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */ background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%,#ededed 100%);
        /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */ filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ededed',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */ } .wrdAdmin h1 { font-size: 18pt; font-weight: bold; padding-bottom:
        12px; } .wrdAdmin h2 { font-size: 16pt; font-weight: bold; padding-bottom: 10px; } .wrdAdmin h3 { font-size: 14pt; font-weight: bold; padding-bottom: 8px; } .wrdAdmin h4 { font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold; padding-bottom: 6px; } .wrdAdmin hr
        { border: thin solid #333; margin-bottom: 12px; }
      </div>
      <br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </div>

  <script src="/Ace/ace-builds/src-noconflict/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script>
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/ambiance");
    editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/css");
    document.getElementById('editor').style.fontSize = '1vw';
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `<input type="textarea">` field to your `form` which is hidden. Add a JavaScript handler that detects when your form is being submitted. This handler should set the value of the hidden input field to the current value of the ACE editor. Then you can read the value of the input field from PHP.

Here is your code modified that does that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>ACE in Action</title>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    body {
      background-color: #ffff;
      color: #333;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .editor_container {
      text-align: center;
    }

    .editor_container form {
      margin: 45px;
      width: 90%;
      border: thin #333;
      border-radius: 8px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .ace_gutter-cell {
      color: white;
      !important
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="editor_container">
    <h1>Ace Editor</h1>
    <form action="update.php" method="post" id="myForm">  <!-- ID added here -->
      <input name="foo" type="text" hidden id="editortext"> <!-- hidden text field here added here-->
      <h2>Edit the CSS file</h2>
      <div id="editor" title="css edit:" style="height: 500px; width: 80%; float: right;">
        .wrdAdmin { border-radius: 8px; border: solid thin #333; margin: auto; padding: 40px; position: relative; /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ffffff+0,ededed+100 */ background: #ffffff; /* Old browsers
        */ background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #ededed 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */ background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#ededed 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */ background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%,#ededed 100%);
        /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */ filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ededed',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */ } .wrdAdmin h1 { font-size: 18pt; font-weight: bold; padding-bottom:
        12px; } .wrdAdmin h2 { font-size: 16pt; font-weight: bold; padding-bottom: 10px; } .wrdAdmin h3 { font-size: 14pt; font-weight: bold; padding-bottom: 8px; } .wrdAdmin h4 { font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold; padding-bottom: 6px; } .wrdAdmin hr
        { border: thin solid #333; margin-bottom: 12px; }
      </div>
      <br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.3.3/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script>
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/ambiance");
    editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/css");
    document.getElementById('editor').style.fontSize = '1vw';

    // added event handler
    document.getElementById("myForm").onsubmit = function(evt) {
      document.getElementById("editortext").value = editor.getValue();
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```